# How to get a html element by name

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way in java script to get only a particular name instead of using `document.getElementsByName("x");` which return an array? I have a kind of special situation where i can’t use the id. Any suggestions please?
Thank You.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just get the first element:

```
document.getElementsByName("x")[0];
```

Or for safety:

```
function getFirstElementByName(element_name) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(element_name);
    if (elements.length) {
        return elements[0];
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

(BTW getElementsByName returns a collection, not an array.)

Comment: in java script is there a real difference between array and a collection?

Comment: Yes. They have different properties.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for a single element, take the first one from the nodelist, for example:

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("x")[0];
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rmJZa/).

Answer (score 0):

Or use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), so you don't have to bother with all the browser annoyance.

You just have to do this:

```
$("*[name='x']").first();
```

To get the first element with that name. If you know the element type than you can use it instead of "*". jQuery will make your life easier every time!

Comment: or $("*[name='x']").first() which won't throw an error, if no element is returned.

Comment: Lovely, somehow I think in this case `getElementsByName` is far less "annoying".