# Writing local storage value inside h2 tag of div element

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple localstorage values that I want to write in the HTML code.

My main `div` name is `data` and there is an `h2` tag inside that `div`

```
<div id="data">
   <h2></h2>
</div>
```

Now if i want to write the value of my `localStorage` to the `data` div i would do this,

```
    document.getElementById("data").innerHtml = localStorage.score;
```

but I want to write it inside the `h2` tag,
So i tried this after searching on Stackoverflow,

```
    document.getElementById("data").getElementsByTagName('h2').innerText = localStorage.score;
```

and this,

```
document.getElementById("data").getElementsByTagName('h2').firstChild.nodeValue = localStorage.score;
```

but both of these are not working.
Why it is not working can anybody tell me ?

Comment: The method getElementsByTagName() returns an array, it accesses all elements with the specified tagname. Use getElementsByTagName('h2')[0] to add value to it. 

Like document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = localStorage.score;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order to get the first element, do not use `firstChild`, rather, use the zero index instead

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]
```

See [How to get a html element by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856697/how-to-get-a-html-element-by-name)

`firstChild` is for nested children, not an array of elements.

Second, use `innerHTML` like you were for 'content'

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = localStorage.score;
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92ogfdrj/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted you need to either change the div id from data to content or change call the getElementById with the "data" parameter.

That is, if there is indeed something in localStorage.score to show.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array, it accesses all elements with the specified tagname. Use `getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]` to add value to it.

Like

`document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = localStorage.score;`