# Javascript Length Undefined or Zero

Tags: javascript, undefined, getelementsbyname

I am trying to write a Javascript function that returns a single element given the name. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856697/how-to-get-a-html-element-by-name) question and modified the answer to use the ternary operator.

```
function getField(fieldName)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(fieldName);

    return elements.length && elements.legth > 0 ? elements[0] : null;
}
```

My question is about the case where `document.getElementsByName(fieldName)` doesn't find any matches. Does it return `undefined` or `0`? When I output `elements.length` as an alert message, the value in the alert is `0` but the console Chrome's DevTools says `undefined`. When I call `console.log(elements.length)` from the console, it ouputs `0` **and** `undefined`.

[image: My tests in Chrome]

I know that my function handles either case, but what am I missing here? What is Javascript actually doing?

Thanks in advance for helping me understand this.

**EDIT:** Sorry for posting a picture instead of actual code and thanks for the syntax clarification.

Comment: Please [include code as text, not as images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). You likely want `elements && elements.length > 0`...

Comment: `alert(something)` returns undefined, as does `console.log()`.

Comment: The first `undefined` is the result that `alert` returns. `console.log` also returns `undefined`, but prints the value of `elements.length` first. See [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14633968/215552)

Comment: `return elements[0] || null;` would be simpler/faster. you can even omit the `null`, since `undefined` is a better (more universal) `null` anyway.

Comment: How come `elements.length` doesn't return undefined or throw an exception? Does `getElementsByName()` return an empty object if no matches are found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question seems to be what [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) is returning when it isn't found, it would be an empty [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), with a length of 0 (so not undefined)

Therefor, the easiest would be as dandavis suggested in his comment to simply return the first element of the nodelist. If it is empty, it will be undefined, if not it would the first element (not sure if that always matches your case though)

so your function might as well be

```
function getFieldAt(fieldName, index = 0) {
  return document.getElementsByName(fieldName)[index];
}
```

if you don't use optional parameters, you could change it to

```
function getFieldAt(fieldName, index) {
  return document.getElementsByName(fieldName)[index || 0];
}
```

Your misunderstanding about the devtools are thoroughly explained in the comments and the other answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

`elements.length` is equal to 0 in your case.

Your understanding of `console.log` is misleading:

```
console.log(elements.length);
> elements.length is printed. It evaluates to 0, so 0 is printed
> console.log(elements.length). It evaluates to undefined, so undefined is printed.
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to test length value simply use:

```js
function getField(fieldName)
{
  let elements = document.getElementsByName(fieldName);
  return (elements[0]) ? elements[0] : null;
}

console.log( getField('div-A') );
console.log( getField('neverExist') );
```

```html
<div name="div-A"> div-A 1 </div>
<div name="div-A"> div-A 2 </div>
<div name="div-A"> div-A 3 </div>
```